# WCF Service response delay

Tags: android, wcf, rest, response, fiddler

I have a WCF Rest service, what I tested with Fiddler, cause I experienced slow performance on  Android mobile devices. I'm not expert in server side, but I see server has latency before writing back response. I copied Fiddler result. What could be the problem?

```
== TIMING INFO ============
ClientConnected:     09:26:06.907
ClientBeginRequest:  09:26:06.907
GotRequestHeaders:   09:26:06.907
ClientDoneRequest:   09:26:06.907
Determine Gateway:   0ms
DNS Lookup:          0ms
TCP/IP Connect:      1222ms
HTTPS Handshake:     0ms
ServerConnected:     09:26:08.130
FiddlerBeginRequest: 09:26:08.130
ServerGotRequest:    09:26:08.131
ServerBeginResponse: 09:26:44.151
GotResponseHeaders:  09:26:44.151
ServerDoneResponse:  09:26:44.151
ClientBeginResponse: 09:26:44.151
ClientDoneResponse:  09:26:44.151

Overall Elapsed:     00:00:37.2441302


The response was buffered before delivery to the client.
```

Service is hosted as a WebServiceHost2.

Service method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Test/PostData", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Stream PostTestData(Stream data);

public Stream PostTestData(Stream data)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Log(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: From your logs, it seems the duration to process the request is around 36 sec. 
Have you tried to calculate the processing time manually inside the method ?

Comment: In this case the service method is almost empty, only contains 1 sec sleep. This method is only for testing.

Comment: have you checked the response status+text or your request ? is the service url reachable ?

Comment: Service is working. HTTP Status is 200. I've got an other service method, which provides a json. I got the json, but this method has the delay too.

ServerConnected:     15:38:52.794
FiddlerBeginRequest: 15:39:31.895
ServerGotRequest:    15:39:31.895
`ServerBeginResponse: 15:39:45.973
GotResponseHeaders:  15:39:45.973
ServerDoneResponse:  15:40:12.142
ClientBeginResponse: 15:40:12.145
ClientDoneResponse:  15:40:12.145`

Comment: is it only on your android device ?

Comment: It's on all device. First I experienced on android, so I checked in Fiddler too. The delay is the same.

Comment: what kindof service is it (Web Api, WCF Rest, ...) ? also, note that a method with a single sleep of 1 sec, can take longer because of init/cleanup code in the service. Can you show the service ?